# Something like unnecessary code detector for NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

NetBeans is by default better than Eclipse (imho) in detecting code smells, but the [Unnecessary Code Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) for Eclipse seems to find more dead code and code that should be improved. Is there something comparable for NetBeans or is there a Maven plug-in?

Comment: Better by default? Trying to start a flamewar? Please add a reference for that statement.

Comment: I don't want to start a flamewar, that was only my subjectiv experience - I marked this in the question now. There were much better areas to start an anti Eclipse flamewar ;-)

Comment: Bug 197574 - RFE: Unneeded code detection.
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197574

Answer (score 7):

Not a direct answer to your question, but this might be interesting: Here is a [set of plugins](https://sqe.dev.java.net/) for NetBeans to integrate tools like FindBugs, PMD and CheckStyle into NetBeans.

Those tools are static code analysis tools: they look at your source code and give you information about possible error-prone constructs, possible bugs etc. and can most likely also find unused code.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this plugin: [dead code detector](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50005/dead-code-detector).

It is a sort of proof-of-concept plugin build on Emeric Vernat's [DCD project](https://github.com/evernat/dead-code-detector).

*ps. there is also a [feature request [Bug 181458]](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181458) on which you can **vote** to get this feature in Netbeans out-of-the-box :-)*

Answer (score 1):

The ucdetector is strictly limited to eclipse and can't be used in a different environment. So if you wanted to use it, you'd have to install a basic eclipse somewhere with [projects pointing to your source directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174308/using-both-eclipse-and-netbeans-on-the-same-project) and use it for unused code detection only.

Another way to identify unused code is instrumenting the (live) application, run it for a while and analyse the logs. Usual tools are Emma, Cobertura, and Clover.

---

<sub>Couldn't resist - detecting code smells with eclipse...</sub>

- [Checkstyle plugin for eclipse](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/)
- [PMD integration for eclipse](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html)
- [findbugs integration for eclipse](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html)